# How to plot logarithm functions on Google search graphing tool

Tags: graphing-functions

I've using Google search engine graphing tool for a while, but now I'm trying to plot a logarithm function like :$\log_2(x + 1) + 2$

How to pass this notation for the graphing tool ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the change of base formula:

$$
\log_b(a)=\frac{\log_c(a)}{\log_c(b)}
$$

So for you example, you would do:

$$
\frac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln(2)}+2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just Google for [lg(x+1) + 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=lg%28x%2b1%29%2b2). Here “lg” is the standard notation in computer science for a base-two logarithm.

If you didn’t know that, you could have got the same graph by typing [log(x+1)/log(2) + 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=log%28x%2b1%29%2Flog%282%29%2b2), making use of the fact that $\log_k(x) = \log_n(x)/\log_n(k)$ for any base $n$.